# Loading a function on pageload wont load Laravel 5.0

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I currently call a file using onload in javascript.
It works fine, I just can't seem to get it to work in Laravel, if I load an html file it's fine, but not a php file.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#query").load("test.php");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id="query"><img src='https://m.popkey.co/163fce/Llgbv_s-200x150.gif'/></div>
<div id="query2"><img src='https://m.popkey.co/163fce/Llgbv_s-200x150.gif'/></div>
```

Results are blank.

The `test.php` file is located in the public folder, it just has a simple echo in it:

```
<?php echo 'This is Working';
```

I have a `test.html` in the same folder that returns what ever I put in it perfectly, it seems to be an issue with javascript pulling the php file.
If i run this url : `https://domain/Home/public/test.html` it works fine, if i run this url `https://Domain/Home/public/test.php` it also works fine. The `test.php` echo's out `This is Working`

Comment: What do you get when you go to test.php directly in your browser? Are you sure the page works? it doesn't seem to be related to the JS code you have.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, yeah i think it has something to do with Laravel

Comment: Then post your laravel code

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo , i updated my question

Comment: As @jedrzej.kurylo already asked, `What do you get when you go to test.php directly in your browser?`

Comment: *waste. You can ignore the help offered, it is up to you.  `The php file does not run as it's in the public folder` ... what does that mean?

Comment: PHP files work fine in Laravel's `public/` dir. If yours is not, that's the problem.  But we can't help unless we know what actually happens when you try to view it - do you see an error?  Anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back.

What i did was not run the file directly from the public folder, i created a Route.

```
Route::get('test.php', function(){
echo 'This is Working';
);
```

Now you can either run what you want directly from this function or return it to your view.

**Now you can use :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#query").load('test.php');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @MatHatrick , this actually worked and is a better solution for what i am actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What Configuration are you using? This link shows that it's a problem using Laravel Valet. [Github Issue Here](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/424).

I would recommend that you use an API route for loading these images and try to keep everything within the Framework for the sake of neat and tidiness?

#### But for a quick solution:

```
Route::get('foo.php', function () {
    return 'foo';
});
```

#### API: (Within routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return asset('assets/images/image.jpg');
});
```

and your JS would point to your URL of the Route.

Answer (score 0):

Add the script tag of jQuery function in body and make sure you have used jQuery CDN for access the jQuery function

Comment: Could you provide an example please, as i dont understand, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
$("#query").load("{{ asset('public/test.php') }}");
```

I think this solve your problem